# Python server: How to find client's External IP address

Tags: python, server, client, external, ip-address

In my project I have two python files for a client and server.

The client sends his internal IP address to the server.

Then the server must use the client's internal IP to derive the client's external IP, and must then send the external IP back to the client.

I know how to get the external IP of the server by using the 'requests' and 'urllib' libraries, but just not how to get the external IP of the client's address sent to the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: Unless your server is a router or similar I don't think this will work. How could it? Even if it were possible it's important to consider that a machine isn't required to have a single public IP address. It could have zero or many. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to solve by sending to a client machine its own external IP address?

Comment: _"the server must use the client's internal IP to derive the client's external IP"_: What does this even mean? The server should already know the client's external IP (unless they are in the same subnet) since it is the originating IP address.

Comment: @Selcuk, good point. I interpreted "external IP" as "public IP" (and the OP may have meant this) but it isn't clear.

Comment: I'm working on a project where I have to determine the type of NAT that I'm behind by implementing STUN.
The question that I asked is one of the steps involved. To be honest I'm not sure exactly why it's needed.

Comment: The router routes the request to another router and finally say to your HTTP server. The server sees the public IP of the router. Now when you respond, the router takes the response and sends it to whatever hardware(MAC) it is meant for, which it finds out from its own ARP cache. And there the local IP is listed. How can you server **use** the internal IP.